# android NDK compatibility with android level

Tags: android-ndk

I wanted to check the compatibility of the latest LTS NDK toolchain which is 25c with Android API level 28.
Is there a risk of incompatibilities issues if I use this combination ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The current plan is for NDK r25 (2022 LTS) to be the last release that supports KitKat (APIs 19 and 20).
So API level 28 is supported on android LTS r25c NDK.
ref : https://github.com/android/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r25

Answer (score 0):

NDK version and OS version are orthogonal as long as the given NDK supports that OS version. Older NDKs won't support new OS versions, and newer NDKs won't support pointlessly old OS versions.

Without a very compelling reason, always use the latest NDK. Using an older NDK means you will not get support if you encounter bugs.